# Сделать выборку с прошлого понедельника по прошлое воскресенье

Tags: mysql

Нашел такую конструкцию

```
`WHERE WEEK (order_createdAt) = WEEK( current_date)-1 
AND YEAR( order_createdAt) = YEAR( current_date );`
```

Как переделать запрос, чтобы данные брались с прошлого понедельника, а не воскресенья.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прошлый понедельник - это

```
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
```

Соответственно для воскресенья

```
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (1 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
```

Ну или вместо CURRENT_DATE подставьте требуемую дату...

Comment: исправил на `AND order_createdAt < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY`  в то прошлой субботой выборка заканчивалась

Comment: Вопрос, этот запрос в любой день недели будет корректно отрабатывать?

Comment: Ну если не получается разобраться в логике - просто проверьте.